# What does "Race to X" mean?

Tags: tournaments, pool

A local pool hall features weekly 8-ball and 9-ball double-elimination tournaments, and the different tournaments are described as:

- Race to 4
- Race to 4/3
- Race to 2

What do these terms mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the term *[race](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_cue_sports_terms#race)* in billiards means:

> A predetermined, fixed number of games players must win to win a match; "a race to seven" means whomever wins seven games first wins the match.

Here is a [file](http://www.uspfc.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Pocket-Billiards-Rules.pdf) with some more examples:

> First competitor to win 3 matches (race to 3) 
>   First competitor to win 4 matches (race to 4) 
>   First competitor to win 5 matches (race to 5) 
>   First competitor to win 6 matches (race to 6)

As for your "race to 4/3" example, I believe that is specific to double-elimination tournaments in which you play a different number of games depending on whether you are in the winner's bracket or the loser's bracket.  So "race to 4/3" means it's a "race to 4" in the winner's bracket and a "race to 3" in the loser's bracket.  Here's a [page](http://illinoisapa.com/pool-tournaments-events/) where it mentions a different "race" for the winner's and loser's brackets in one tournament:

> Race to 3 winner’s side. Race to 2 on the loser’s side.

If a double-elimination tournament has the same number of games for both the winner's and loser's brackets, then you could call it a "race to N/N".  An example of that can be found [here](http://www.onepocket.org/one_pocket_pool_events.htm):

> race to 3/3 double elimination

But instead of calling it a "race to 3/3", you could just call it a "race to 3".  An example of that can be found [here](http://seminolelargopool.com/pdfs/Tournaments.pdf):

> Double Elimination – Race to 3

Comment: That's a very complicated way of saying "Win x racks to win the match".

Comment: The usual sporting idiom is "first to X" as a shortening of "first to get score X wins the match". The change to using "race to X" instead is not complicated at all.